# Corrupted dependencies when npm installing inside docker container

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, npm, gulp

I am building and running the following `docker-compose` file

```
gulp:
  image: node:4.4
  volumes:
    - ./admin:/node
  working_dir: /node
  command: bash -c "npm install && npm install -g gulp-cli && gulp dev"
```

`npm install` commands go fine, but then `gulp` fails with the following error:

```
admin-gulp_1 | npm info ok 
admin-gulp_1 | /node/node_modules/gulp-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/source-code.js:88
admin-gulp_1 | SourceCode.splitLines = function(text) {
admin-gulp_1 | ^
admin-gulp_1 | 
admin-gulp_1 | ReferenceError: SourceCode is not defined
admin-gulp_1 |     at Object.<anonymous> (/node/node_modules/gulp-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/source-code.js:88:1)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
admin-gulp_1 |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Object.<anonymous> (/node/node_modules/gulp-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:21:18)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
admin-gulp_1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
sf_admin-gulp_1 exited with code 1
```

When I `cat /node/node_modules/gulp-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/source-code.js` I see some strange characters:

```
/**
 * Check to see if its a ES6 export declaration
 * @param {ASTNode} astNode - qa��  B0��    ���7�sa��   B0��    ���7�sa��   B0��    ���7�va��   B0��    ���7|a��    B0���L0��
���$1y���=�s0��1A�$1����=�s0��1A�$1����=�L0���,����=���=�s0��1A�$1!���= B0���޳�7�za��೙7�a��I\�î31A�$11A�$1�B�$1�B�$11s0��1A�$11A�$11s0��1A�$11A�$1!q0��1A�$1I���=p��g�)�node_modules/gulp-plumber/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/graceful-fs$1��g�)�node_modules/gulp-plumber/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-filest:2iC0��@1A�$11s0��1A�$11A�$1!q0��1A�$1����=iC0���y%hc�3�@rU11]0��1A�$1Y�dZ4ٞ0��1A�$11A�$1�S��yA�$1���v<rCommentAfter = tokensAndCommentsStore.getTokenAfter;

    // don't allow modification of this object
    Object.freeze(this);
    Object.freeze(this.lines);
}

/**
 * Split the source code into multiple lines based on the line delimiters
 * @param {string} text Source code as a string
 * @returns {string[]} Array of source code lines
 * @public
 */
SourceCode.splitLines = function(text) {
    return text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n|\u2028|\u2029/g);
};
```

If I repeat the process, the error does not always happen in the same file, but it is always about wrong characters in any of the files `npm` installs.
If I then run bash in the container and individually `npm install` the specific modules whose files are corrupted, then they get fixed and `gulp` succeeds.
If I instead run `npm install` and `gulp` in the host machine, everything works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to be related to the docker-machine RAM memory. When I set it to 1024MB instead of 512MB, there are no corrupted dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **locale** correct. Most docker images don't specify locales.

```
FROM ubuntu:lastest

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

Source [Docker and Locales](http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/)